# Blazored LocalStorage - what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

im learning blazor still - wanted to add something so simple popular Blazored LocalStorage
but have some basic trouble / question

code is:

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
 using S3.Client.Shared.Services;
 using System.Security.Claims;

 namespace S3.Client.Helpers
  {
    public class MyAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
      private Blazored.LocalStorage.ISyncLocalStorageService l;
      public MyAuthenticationStateProvider(Blazored.LocalStorage.ISyncLocalStorageService l)
      {
        this.l= l;
      }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        AuthenticationState aut;

        var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "xxxyyyzzz"),
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator")
                };

        ClaimsPrincipal p = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
        l.SetItem<ClaimsPrincipal>("User", p);

        ClaimsPrincipal principal =  l.GetItem<ClaimsPrincipal>("User");


        bool x = p == principal;


        if (principal != null && principal.Claims.Count() >0 )
        {
            aut = new AuthenticationState(principal);
        }
        else
        {
            var anonymous = new ClaimsIdentity();
            aut = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(anonymous));
        }
         return await Task.FromResult(aut);
```

and please tell me

why x is FALSE ? it should be same object ?

```
bool x = p.Claims.Count() == principal.Claims.Count()
```

still false.
in debug i see in p._identities =1 a,d in principal._identities =0...

thanks and regards

Comment: Not really. Storing an object and then retrieving it almost never (in any technology) gives you the very same object in terms of reference equality. Thus `p != principal`, however, if you take a look **into** the principal and check out claims it contains, claims should be the same. In other words, replace your reference equality code (`p == principal`) with content equality code (equal claim values).

Comment: hi thanks you are right  but this is not that issue . i updated qestion

Comment: I'd assume now that the JSON serializer used to store/retrieve the data just doesn't like how the `Principal` is structured (and somehow misses the claims collection). If I were you, I'd try to extract claims to simple data objects (type/value) and store the claim collection as an array. If this works, you'd have your answer.

Comment: ok you are right now thanks. so it is for simple objects not that complex. please post answer i will accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer accepted by the OP in the comments below the question:

The most probable cause of the serialization/deserialization issue is that the JSON serializer used to store/retrieve the data just doesn't like how the `Principal` is structured (and thus the serializer somehow ignores the claims collection).

A workaround would be to extract claims to simple data objects (type/value) and store the claim collection as simple array.